# Import web3 could not be resolvedpylance(reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I keep getting this problem i don't know why it keeps on telling me import web3 can't be resolved no matter how many times i try to reinstall and install it
please help me out if anyone can
this is the code

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import json
from ***web3*** import Web3


with open("./SimpleStorage.sol") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()
    print(simple_storage_file)

# Compile our solidity code
install_solc("0.6.0")
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evnm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)
with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

# get bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]

# get abi
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]

# for connecting to ganache
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"))
chain_id = 5777
my_address = "0x1973268d75BaFcf21C6D2dFF604a0d64d0158E50"
private_key = "0x842565ffcef56f602eb72494a4bde5e1c45192069b7a5bc9775ac1a00a58aa51"

# Create our first contract

SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
print(SimpleStorage)
```

i get a problem at line 3 which is ***web3***  i had put these stars to recognise i have not included in actual code

Answer (score 0):

1. I would make sure you did `pip install web3` in the terminal
2. Once you've installed web3 I would do **cmd + shift + p** and search for **Reload Window**
   [VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZFQ3.png)

... This will update VS Code and get rid of any unwanted errors

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I figured out that I had Anaconda installed, a different environment calling my library and executing the code.
I fixed that switching the environment to base/Conda environment in VS.

[switching interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAkUw.png)In the botton-left corner you can switch the interpreter (python), I was having a different interpreter and the web3 library was in the base interpreter.